# controlled input in PureComponent not render on change

Tags: reactjs

Why PureComponent doesn't rendered when controlled input change

changing to Component solves it

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

class Contact extends PureComponent {
state = {firstName:''}

 handleInput = ({ target }, name) => {
 const state = this.state;
 state[name] = target.value;
 this.setState(state);
};

render(){
 return (
    <input onChange={e => {
             this.handleInput(e, 'firstName');
           }} 
           value={this.state.firsName} />
  )
 }
}
```

it should render the new state on typing,
but it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it like this instead:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

class Contact extends PureComponent {
  state = {firstName:''}
  handleInput = name => ({target}) => this.setState({[name]: target.value})


  render() {
    return (
      <input
        onChange={this.handleInput('firstName')} 
        value={this.state.firsName} />
    )
  }
}
```

The main problem that you were having was the fact that you were directly mutating the state object, what you were doing is like doing this: `this.state.someProp = 'foo'; this.setState(this.state);`, which is bad. You should never directly mutate the `state`.

The other thing that I'm doing differently is that I have converted the `handleInput` method into a Higher Order Function... That wasn't necessary, but IMO makes the code a bit cleaner. Basically what that means is that `this.handleInput('whatever')` is going to return a function that accepts the "event" as its first (and only) parameter and updates the `whatever` property of the state.

Comment: it indeed solve the problem.
can you explain two thing pls
a. why it work now
b. what is this 

name => ({target}) => this.setState({[name]: target.value})

Comment: @eladBA of course, give me a sec, I will update my answer in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

```js
class Contact extends React.PureComponent {
  state = { firstName: "" };

  handleInput = ({ target }, name) => {
    const newState = {...this.state,[name]:target.value};
    this.setState(newState);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <p>{this.state.firstName}</p>
      <input
        onChange={e => {
          this.handleInput(e, "firstName");
        }}
        value={this.state.firsName}
      />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Contact />,document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```